# How to change value of input type field from clicked HTML row table?

Tags: javascript, html, web

So here is my full code, i try to connect database with html table, and i'd like to change the value of input type with the data from the table :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MAHASISWA</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="code.ico">
<style>
  #data tr:hover{
    background-color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #data tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  #data th{
    background: #fff;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:cornsilk">
<form action="<?php echo "mahasiswa.php"?>" method="post">
  <fieldset align="center" style="border:5px solid black;margin:0px 500px">
    <legend>Data</legend>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>NIM</td>
        <td><input min="0" type="number" name="nim"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nama</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nama"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jurusan</td>
        <td><select name="jurusan" style="width:173px">
          <option value="Sistem Informasi">Sistem Informasi</option>
          <option value="Teknik Industri">Teknik Industri</option>
          <option value="Teknik Informatika">Teknik Informatika</option>
          <option value="Ilmu Komputasi">Ilmu Komputasi</option>
          <option value="Sistem Komputer">Sistem Komputer</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="INPUT"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="update" value="DELETE" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="delete" value="UPDATE" disabled></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  </form>

<table id="data" border="1" style="margin-top:50px" align="center">
  <caption align="center">Tabel Data Mahasiswa</caption>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <strong>
    <th width="150px">NIM</th>
    <th width="250px">Nama</th>
    <th width="250px">Jurusan</th>
    </strong>
  </tr>
      <?php
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "belajar");
      $query = "select * from mahasiswa";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
          ?>
          <tr onclick="settext(this.index)">
            <td><?php echo $row[0]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[1]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[2]?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
      }
     ?>
</table>
<script>
  function settext(x) {
    var table = document.getElementById('id');
    var a = table.rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML;
    var b = table.rows[x].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var c = table.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML;
    document.getElementByName('nim').value = parseInt(a);
    document.getElementById('nama').value = b;
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = c;
    opt.innerHTML = c;
    document.getElementById('jurusan').appendChild(opt);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way by using javascript, to change the value of these 3 input types matching the clicked-row?

P.S : Sorry for bad English

Comment: Have you properly configured the on click event for the table row?

Comment: @JoeyPinto I edited the question, i attach the click event

Comment: What is the select supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
HTML code

```
<table id="data" border="1" style="margin-top:50px" align="center"> 
<caption align="center">Tabel Data Mahasiswa</caption>
<tr style="text-align:center">
<strong>
<th width="150px">NIM</th>
<th width="250px">Nama</th>
<th width="250px">Jurusan</th>
</strong>
</tr>
<tr onclick="settext(this.rowIndex)">
<td>1</td>
<td>Data2</td>
<td>Data3</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="settext(this.rowIndex)">
<td>4</td>
<td>Data5</td>
<td>Data6</td>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="number" id="fordata1">
<input type="text" id="fordata2">
<select id="fordata3" style="width:173px" >

</select>
```

Javascript

```
function settext(x){
var table = document.getElementById('data');
var a = table.rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML;
var b = table.rows[x].cells[1].innerHTML;
var c = table.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML;
document.getElementById('fordata1').value = parseInt(a);
document.getElementById('fordata2').value = b;
document.getElementById('fordata3').innerText = null;
 var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = c;
opt.innerHTML = c;
document.getElementById('fordata3').appendChild(opt);
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4x987tf/)

Comment: Look at your browser console for errors, there were many typos in your code.

Comment: It's seems  your answer is right, but i still got nothing

Comment: Did you try the JS Fiddle link?

Comment: Accept the answer, if you don't understand something we're glad to help.

Comment: I tried it, and it works fine.. I try to use it to my code but it doesnt change.. if you dont mind, i edited the question with my full code.

Comment: Thanks by the way :)

Comment: Give me a moment, mind accepting the solution till then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function settext(x){
    var tabel = document.getElementById('data');
    var cells = tabel.rows[x].getElementsByTagName('td');

    var a = cells[0].innerHTML;
    var b = cells[1].innerHTML;
    var c = cells[2].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByid('fordata1').value = a;
    document.getElementsByid('fordata2').value = b;
    document.getElementsByid('fordata3').value = c;
}
```

Comment: @Haze you have retained his typos.

Comment: @JoeyPinto yep, sorry for that

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple approach

```html
<table id="data" border="1" style="margin-top:50px" align="center">
    <caption align="center">Tabel Data Mahasiswa</caption>
    <tr style="text-align:center">
    <strong>
    <th width="150px">NIM</td>
    <th width="250px">Nama</td>
    <th width="250px">Jurusan</td>
    </strong>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="settext(this)">
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="settext(this)">
    <td>Dataa</td>
    <td>Datab</td>
    <td>Datac</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="number" id="fordata1">
<input type="text" id="fordata2">
<select id="fordata3" style="width:173px">
</select>

<script>
function settext(x){
    var tds = x.children;
    var a = tds[0].innerHTML;
    var b = tds[1].innerHTML;
    var c = tds[2].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('fordata1').value = a;
    document.getElementById('fordata2').value = b;
    document.getElementById('fordata3').value = c;
  }
</script>
```